# Python, PyFITS, cannot open file

Tags: python, file, pyfits

I have problem in opening FITS file in Python. I get following error-message:

```
File "G:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyfits\file.py", line 416, in _open_filelike % self.mode)  
IOError: File-like object does not have a 'write' method, required for mode 'ostream'
```

at `hdulist = pft.open(path)` line (I did import `pyfits` as `pft`).

I checked the path twice - it's correct.
I'm not able to find any reference to this error in context of using PyFITS and I will be gratefull for any help.

**UPDATE:**
I missed some details and I'm sorry for it.
First of all: I'm using PyFITS 3.3 under Anaconda distribution for Windows (Windows XP 32-bit).
Code of whole widget you can find at this link:
[FileView](http://pastebin.com/GpXp4MWK)
In a short - I'm making simple explorer for filesystem, just to let user navigate to folder with FITS files and read it from folder. All project is under PyQT4.

Comment: Please provide [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). i.e. show us your code, not a line from it, tell us about PyFITS version (Anaconda version?)

Comment: Ye, thanks, I did really forget how to ask a question properly:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously your `path` is not a subclass of `basestring` (I suppose you use Python 2.7) as it is expected by PyFITS. In fact `path` is a `QString` instance and you have to convert to `unicode` first.

So replace your line

```
hdulist = pft.open(path)
```

with

```
hdulist = pft.open(unicode(path.toUtf8(), encoding="UTF-8"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I always have problem with this encoding stuff.