# Python function with a list of files as argument?

Tags: python, function

I'm building a function that needs to operate over several files, in the following way:

```
def myfuntion(filenames):
    n = len(filenames)
    if n > 0:
        data = fits.open(filenames)
        for i in range(1,n):
            final = *DO SOMETHING FOR EACH FILE*
    return final
```

The idea is to call the function using several files:

```
mean_myfuntion(['file1.fits', 'file2.fits', 'file3.fits'])
```

However the problem is that I'm receiving the following error:

```
OSError: File-like object does not have a 'write' method, required for mode 'ostream'.
```

And I'm not sure what's going on. I'm suspecting that I'm missing something when calling the filenames (***data = fits.open(filenames)***), If you folks have any advise, it will be more than welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: can you add the `DO SOMETHING FOR EACH FILE` part ?

Comment: Where does in [its documentation](http://astropy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/io/fits/api/files.html) says that it can work with list of filenames? It clearly expects a single file name at once hence you need to loop over filenames and pass one at a time.

Comment: Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703939/python-pyfits-cannot-open-file

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, you are giving a `list` as an arugument to `fits.open()` but the `str` is required:
see [Docs](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/).
So you need to loop through the list to get file name one by one as 'str'.

```
def myfuntion(filenames):
    n = len(filenames)
    if n > 0:
        for file in filenames:
            data = fits.open(file)
            final = *DO SOMETHING FOR EACH FILE*
    return final
```